Update table column based on join in Oracle
I have 2 tables like below:
select vsat_detail_id, sap_id, AZIMUTH_GSAT_16 from tbl_vsat_mst_detail_2409 where vsat_detail_id = 104; Table 1
select vsat_id, sap_id, azimuth_60_e from tbl_vsat_mst_detail where vsat_id = 104; Table 2
So I am updating like below:-
MERGE
 INTO    tbl_vsat_mst_detail trg
USING   (
    SELECT  t1.AZIMUTH_GSAT_16 AS rid, t2.azimuth_60_e as code
    FROM    tbl_vsat_mst_detail_2409 t1
    JOIN    tbl_vsat_mst_detail t2
    ON      t1.vsat_detail_id = t2.vsat_id
    WHERE   t1.vsat_detail_id = 104
    ) src
ON      (trg.rowid = src.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET trg.value = code;

but nothing is getting updated. Please help

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your tables and sample data; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you are trying to implement; and the expected output after the merge. At the moment you have two queries at the start of the question and then the MERGE statement refers to a value column that is not referenced in those initial queries so it is unclear what your table structure looks like and what the exact logic is that you are trying to implement.

You are comparing the ROWID pseudo-column for the tbl_vsat_mst_detail table to the AZIMUTH_GSAT_16 column of the  tbl_vsat_mst_detail_2409 table. Those two are unlikely to be equal so it is unsurprising that they do not match.
You probably want something like:
MERGE INTO tbl_vsat_mst_detail trg
USING      tbl_vsat_mst_detail_2409 src
ON  (   src.vsat_detail_id = trg.vsat_id
    AND src.vsat_detail_id = 104)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET trg.azimuth_60_e = src.AZIMUTH_GSAT_16;

